# Boltzmann–Gibbs-distribution as resulting from a limiting density of states?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I'm interested in the relation between the probability distribution $p_i$ over states of a system on the one side and the density of states $\rho(\eta)$ of its environment. (Meaning, $\int_{\eta_a}^{\eta_b} \rho(\eta) ~ \mathrm{d} \eta$ is the number of environment states with energies in the interval $[\eta_a, \eta_b]$.)

If the whole (system + environment) is energetically closed ("isolated") with a total energy $E = e + \eta$, but system and environment are in thermal equilibrium (i.e. the whole is described by the microcanonical ensemble), then it holds
$$
p_i = \frac{ \rho(E - e_i) }{ \sum_i \rho(E - e_i) }.
$$

This means, the probability distribution over states of the system is determined by
a) something that only characterizes the energetic *structure* of the system, the $e_i$s
b) something that only characterizes the energetic *structure* of the environment, $\rho(\eta)$, and
c) the total energy $E$.

This relation holds generally, for arbitrarily small or large systems and/or environments. Please note that we have not yet taken any limits!

If we now consider the thermodynamic limit, i.e. an environment composed of an infinite number of subsystems, the probability distribution $p_i$ over states of the system becomes the Boltzmann–Gibbs-distribution (aka canonical ensemble)
$$
p_i = \frac{ \exp(- \beta ~ e_i) }{ \sum_i \exp(- \beta ~ e_i) },
$$
where the sum in the denominator is called the partition function.
Using the first relation above, this distribution could now be interpreted as corresponding to a *limiting density of states of the environment* of the form
$$
\rho(\eta) \propto \exp( \beta \eta )
$$
which characterizes the "infinite environment". However, the expression refers to the parameter $\beta$ of the Boltzmann–Gibbs distribution, which represents the temperature and depends on the total energy $E$ (per subsystem). Whereas in the finite case $E$ only serves to connect $\rho(\eta)$ and $p_i$, it here defines $\rho(\eta)$ itself.

To me this suggests that it does not make sense to characterize an infinite environment by a density of states — but maybe there's some way around this? Or is there a mistake in the derivation somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When one proves that a small part of a greater system is described canonical ensemble, even though the greater system is described by a microcanonical ensemble, the key point is that the density of states of the greater system has the exponential form you mention, *over a certain interval of energy*.

Specifically what is important is that $\log \rho(\eta) = {\rm const} + \beta \eta$ over the range $\eta = \langle\eta \rangle \pm \Delta e$, where $\Delta e$ is the energy fluctuation of the small system, and $\langle \eta \rangle = E - \langle e \rangle$ is the expected energy. The value of $\rho(\eta)$ is not really important for energies that are very far outside this range, since those energies never occur.

In practice the form of $\rho(\eta)$ is usually something like $\log\rho(\eta) \approx {\rm const} + N \log \eta$ for some very large $N$ (such a form is found for gases, in particular). This log can be taylor expanded to yield the needed form for the canonical ensemble. For a large environment (one that is essentially in the thermodynamic limit and much larger than the attached system), the first order expansion is very accurate over the relevant energy range.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. From what you write I take it that the "limiting density" I was thinking about doesn't really exist generally, but one has to look at a limit of the *local* density around $E$, and the choice of this $E$ determines the resulting $\beta$.

Comment: I did some numerical computations where I arbitrarily fix a $\rho_1(\eta)$ characterizing one environmental element, and then compute the energy density $\rho_N(\eta)$ of the combination of a large number of such elements (without special tricks I get up to about $N = 8 \cdot 10^{6}$ before overflowing double precision). The results suggest that quite independent of the form of $\rho_1(\eta)$, $\rho_N(\eta)$ practically always appears to have the form you mention ($\propto \eta^N$). Do you know of an exact result that states under which conditions this happens?

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting point. I was actually thinking about ideal gases in particular where $\eta^N$ is easy to show. In the general case, what you have when combining elements is that the overall density of states is a repeated convolution of the elements' density of states. If the element density of states has a power law behaviour for energies near the minimum energy, then the convolution will behave as $\eta^N$ for energies near the minimum energy.

Comment: There is probably some sort of general theorem there, but I'm not sure what it would be called. It is related to the central limit theorem which also concerns the result of taking many convolutions.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been thinking of, and I did some research, but couldn't find anything. The crucial difference to the standard central limit theorem(s) is that the single variables involved have to be of finite spread (variance), which is not necessarily the case for $\rho_1(\eta)$. It's of course easy to show that $\rho_N(\eta) \propto \eta^N$ if $\rho_1(\eta) = const.$, but I think it's much more general than that.

Answer (score 0):

The right relationship between the two (the two distributions are pretty much the microcanonical and canonical ensemble) is that the first distribution – all states with some fixed energy – is almost exactly the same (the difference goes to zero if the environment becomes infinite) as the Boltzmann-Gibbs distribution for an appropriate inverse temperature $\beta$.

However, the right value of $\beta$ has to be carefully adjusted for the two distributions to match in the limit. This appropriate temperature may be essentially extracted from the energy of the environment (or energy of everything, it isn't any different in the infinite-environment limit) divided by its number of degrees of freedom, $\beta=\beta(E/N)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think either I misunderstand you or you misunderstood me. – The question is exclusively about a system in thermal equilibrium with an environment, so the microcanonical ensemble does not apply to the system (but only to system + environment).

Comment: I'm interested in the relation between the probability distribution over states of the system $p_i$ and the density of states of the environment $\rho(\eta)$, a) in the general case and b) in the case of the thermodynamic limit, where $p_i$ becomes the BGD / canonical ensemble. $\rho$ characterizes only the energetic structure of the environment, and the total energy $E$ is an additional piece of information needed to formulate the relation between $p_i$ and $\rho$.

Comment: As far as I can see, the first displayed equation holds generally for a system in thermal equilibrium with an environment, at least a finite one. The question is, does it still make sense in the thermodynamic limit (an infinite environment)? If yes, the third displayed equation should hold. However, $\rho(\eta)$ is supposed to characterize the structure of energy states of the environment generally, but via $\beta$ it depends, as you correctly write, on the temperature / energy per degree of freedom.

Comment: I suspect that it is just not possible to characterize an environment with infinitely many degrees of freedom by such a limiting density of states – am I correct? – I'll revise the question along the lines of these comments.

Comment: Dear @A.Donda, you wrote that the total energy is given so be sure that the microcanonical ensemble (for the whole system including the environment) *is* what is relevant. Considering all microstates with a fixed energy (or one in an interval) is how the microcanonical ensemble is defined. This implies some probabilities for the small subsystems of interest and they're almost identical to those from a canonical ensemble at a fixed temperature and the temperature is closely related to the energy of the whole system.

Comment: I tried to write down the correct relationships between the quantities but you seem to insist on some incorrect ones; in this sense, you are not asking a question or listening to the answer. The density of states of the environment has no impact on the probabilities in the small subsystem of interest; the environment only affects the subsystem of interest via its temperature (and/or energy per degree of freedom, which is almost the same information in the limit of the infinite environment). The environment has infinitely many microstates and that's enough for it to act as a heat bath.

Comment: Dear Luboš, yes, the whole is characterized by the microcanonical ensemble, but the probability distribution I'm considering is that of the small system, and this distribution is not the equidistribution over all states with a given energy, so *this* distribution *is* not the microcanonical ensemble, it just *results* from the microcanonical ensemble.

Comment: More importantly, please note that I did not say that the environment has infinitely many degrees of freedom *in general*. I'm first considering the finite case and then the thermodynamic limit, and then try to connect the two results. In the finite case, as far as I can see the probability distribution over states of the system is determined by the density of states of the environment. In case I'm wrong, please tell me why. – I thoroughly revised and extended the question, please have a look.

Comment: Dear @A.Donda, concerning your first point, I agree, the reduction of the microcanonical ensemble to a subsystem isn't a microcanonical ensemble, it's very close to the canonical one. A finite environment is fine but as long as you won't be able to see the difference between the microcanonical and canonical ensembles for the environment, they can't have an impact on the subsystem of interest, either. The (almost) whole point of statistical physics is that generic microstates look thermal i.e. only depend on the temperature, so the dependence on details of the environment just goes away.

Comment: Yes, I understand that this is the point of statistical physics. Basically the motivation behind this question is to see in detail how and why exactly the limiting process removes the dependency on the details of the environment. That's why I start with the finite case, where I can apply the microcanonical ensemble to see the relation between $p_i$ and $\rho(\eta)$. (Note that in this finite case, $p_i$ does not have to be close to the canonical ensemble at all!)

Comment: I had then imagined that the dependence of the details of the environment goes away because there is some kind of limit theorem which shows that $\rho_n(\eta)$, where $n$ is the number of subsystems / degrees of freedoms, converges onto some generic form for $n \to \infty$, similar to what is shown by the central limit theorem in mathematical statistics. Apparently, this doesn't work.

Comment: Am I right to assume that $p_i = \frac{ \rho(E - e_i) }{ \sum_i \rho(E - e_i) }$ results from the microcanonical ensemble for a finite environment?

Comment: Dear @A.Donda, your ratio formula for $p_i$ just follows from - or is - Bayesian inference. Note that in this ratio, "almost everything" about the environmental degrees of freedom cancels out. If you double the density $\rho$ in the relevant interval of the argument, both the numerator and the denominator doubles and the factors of two cancel. You are absolutely right that the canonical Boltzmann (exp. decreasing) form of the probability follows from "something analogous to the central limit theorem".

Comment: The Boltzmann distribution may be derived in many - morally equivalent - ways. Something you say about the would-be derivation you propose is right, something is not right, and it's hard to help you because you don't want to distinguish these two groups of ideas. One basic wrong expectation you are doing is that things are simpler for a finite environment. In statistical physics, just the opposite holds: things simplify in the opposite, thermodynamic limit. That's when the formulae become simple.

Comment: For a system interacting with a finite environment, you get your formulae etc. and for a general finite environment with some states, the functions are complicated and dependent on all details of the environment, all the spectrum etc., and there is really nothing else one can say about them. But  statistical physics only begins once we realize how things simplify in the large $N$ limit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm revisiting my own question after almost a year to add an answer that to my mind clears the matter up. This answer does not add much beyond @Nanite's, but spells out the details. Comments are welcome!

If the environment has an $N$-dimensional state space, for large $N$ its density of states over energy $\eta$ will typically* have the form
$$
\rho(\eta) = a_N ~ \eta ^ {N-1}
$$
($-1$ because the $\rho$ is the *derivative* of the state space volume).

For the numerator of the probability distribution $p_i$ it follows
$$
\rho(E - e_i) = a_N ~ (E - e_i)^{N-1} = a_N E ~ \left (1 - \frac{e_i}E \right )^{N-1}.
$$
If for increasing $N$ we keep the total energy per dimension constant, $\frac EN = \epsilon$,
$$
\rho(E - e_i) = a_N N \epsilon ~ \left (1 - \frac{e_i/\epsilon}{N} \right )^{N-1},
$$
the power term becomes $\exp(-\frac{e_i}\epsilon)$ in the limit $N \to \infty$.

However, the limit of the full state density $\rho(E - e_i)$ depends on the behavior of $a_N N$. A typical* behavior appears to be $a_N \propto \frac1{N!}$, and therefore the density converges to 0. An infinite environment can therefore not be meaningfully characterized by a density of states, even locally.

Proper limiting behavior for the probability distribution does arise since
$$
p_i = \frac{ \rho(E - e_i) }{ \sum_i \rho(E - e_i) }
= \frac{ \left (1 - \frac{e_i/\epsilon}{N} \right )^{N-1} }{ \sum_i \left (1 - \frac{e_i/\epsilon}{N} \right )^{N-1} }
$$
which becomes the Boltzmann–Gibbs-distribution
$$
p_i = \frac{ \exp(-\frac{e_i}\epsilon) }{ \sum_i \exp(-\frac{e_i}\epsilon) }
$$
for $N \to \infty$ — and we see that the temperature of the small system is determined by the energy per dimension of the environment, $1/\beta = \epsilon$.

What we can do is use this limiting behavior to locally *approximate* $\rho(\eta)$ around $\eta = N \epsilon$ for large but finite $N$:
$$
\rho(\eta) \approx a_N \exp(1 - N) \frac N\beta ~ \exp ( \beta ~ \eta )
\quad \propto \exp( \beta ~ \eta )
$$
The dependence on $\beta$ now appears as a natural consequence of the circumstance that we approximate locally around $N \epsilon = \frac N\beta$.

---

*) The weak point of this answer is of course that it assumes a "typical" state density of a high-dimensional environment of the form
$$
\rho(\eta) = a_N ~ \eta ^ {N-1}
$$
or even
$$
\rho(\eta) = a_0 ~ \frac1{N!} ~ \eta ^ {N-1}
$$
with $a_0$ not or only weakly dependent on $N$.